# Group attitude hinders fun

Tags: gm-techniques, problem-players

I have been running my last campaign for over two months and last week some problems occurred during the game.  Two players (I will call them *Warforged* and *Orc*) felt very dissatisfied with the group attitude.
I have discussed this with players, separately, and it appears that the game is no more fun for at least one of them.

#### The Group

The group consists of usual 4 players for some campaign over last 2 years, and 2 new players on my campaign, who only experience one-shot sessions before.

#### The Game

The campaign is oriented towards colonizing a new land in a harsh world and building its own organization to match players' background. PVP is allowed, but it's not the aim of the campaign.  They have plenty to do and decisions to make to survive.

One player, *Orc*, blames passive players to do participate fully in groups, taking egoistic decisions or worst, backstabbing group.  It's sometimes true, especially with new players.

A few weeks ago a problem occurred, a group decision was not followed by a group action, letting one player, *Warforged*, take care of the problem alone which he failed.

Now players are resenting each other for not acting. *Warforge*d feels betrayed and *Orc*, who doesn't act because he was afraid of others player's reactions, blames other for not being participative and DM for not punishing passive players.
They do not want to play again in these conditions.

I had talked to the players, but they didn't recognize their share in the problem.

I want for all people to have fun, it is possible to bring them back together?

Comment: I don't get this sentence: "as new player, a lot of his actions are questionable, chaotic, and he has an history to backstab players": how can he already have "an history to backstab players" while being "a new player" ?

Comment: "Here's a whole campaign worth of events, with plenty of problems only barely sketched, what do I do to fix my game" is too broad for our format and certainly requires a forum-like back and forth to perform analysis of what's up.

Comment: It's his campaign, not his first session, and he has tried to kill another player for pointless reasons before, without success.

Comment: Sorry, I was in the middle of an answer when this got closed.  @mxyzplk makes a good point; you'll have better chances at an idea generating [discussion on a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566).  This question need to be far more tightly focused.  Let's start with your objective: is your objective to convince *Orc* or *Warforged* back to playing, or do you need to solve the problem of what to do with the campaign now that you have two primary players leaving?

Comment: My objectives is to bringthe group back together if it's possible. I don't mind twisting plot or changing my methods, I have at least one player leaving for two months.

Comment: @mxyzplk edited to have clear objective, and no trivial details

Comment: Less information isn't better. With this kind of vague question all you're going to get is the generic answers - "talk it out!" "same page tool!" whatever.  It doesn't help that the middle section of the question is pretty unclear grammatically (who blames who for what?) but also working through this needs to know who's the new players, who's the old, what they do enjoy about the game, etc.  Best take it to chat instead, this still isn't meaningfully answerable.